# Passing the query param from top level to filed level

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have a graphql query like the following:

```
userInfo (id: userId) {
   name
   email

   address {
      street
      country
   }
}
```

So the `name` and `email` will be resolved by a rest endpoint called `details`, however the `address` fields needs to be resolved by another rest endpoint called `address`. `address` rest endpoint also needs the `userId` passed in `userInfo` (as my rest service expects that field). I'm not sure, how I can design my resolver in this case?

With same regards, can a field once resolved can send data to another field? Is that possible in grapqhql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GraphQL, every field is said to *resolve* to a particular value. In GraphQL.js, this value is either whatever value was returned by the resolver, or, if the resolver returned a Promise, whatever that Promise resolved to. This value is what is passed down to each child field's resolver as the first parameter.

In practice, this means that even though your type has specific fields and the object you return should match those fields, it can also include any number of *additional* properties.

For example, your `userInfo` resolver can something look like this:

```
async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  const { name, email } = await getDetails(args.id)
  return {
    name
    email
    id: args.id,
  }
}
```

Even though you don't have an `id` field, we can still include that in the object we return. This way, we can pass some additional info, like our arguments, down to the resolvers of any children fields. Then, inside your `address` resolver:

```
async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  // `parent` contains `name`, `email` and `id` properties
  return getAddress(parent.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add (to @daniel answer) that you can pass this id explicitely in query (w/o `address` resolver changes).

```
userInfo (id: userId) {
  name
  email

  address (userID: userId) {
    street
    country
  }
}
```

To make it (`address` resolver) universal we can use both parameter sources:

```
async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  // `parent` (user) can contain `id` property
  return getAddress(args.userID ? args.userID : parent.id)
}
```

because you should have a possibility to query only address (for given `userId`) as it is possible with rest api.